# Is it possible to use one graphics card for applications and another one for outputting video?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, x11, amd-graphics

Is it possible to use one graphics card for applications (browser, video editor, blender, games, etc.) and another one for outputting video (the other one does not have enough ports)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible with [PRIME](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME) to offload rendering to a dedicated GPU. For NVIDIA graphic cards there is also [Bumblebee](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bumblebee) and [NVIDIA Optimus](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus).

But it also depends on your hardware. I think older hardware may not support hybrid graphics technology.